# Finding all local extrema from a list of values

Tags: numpy, loops, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

This is my code, I receive an error that "list index out of range", I tried to solve this by accounting for the first and last value before the for loop, however I can not figure out how to make the for loop exclude the first and last object, any ideas?

```
def minmax(List):

    mins=[]
    maxs=[]

    if List[0]>List[1]: maxs.append(List[0])
    if List[0]<List[1]: mins.append(List[0])
        
    if List[-1]>List[-2]: maxs.append(List[-1])
    if List[0]<List[1]: mins.append(List[-1])
        
    for i in List[1:-1]:
        if List[i] < List[i-1] and List[i] < List[i+1]:
            mins.append(List[i])
        elif List[i] > List[i-1] and i> List[i+1]:
            maxs.append(List[i])
    return "mins",mins,"maxs",maxs
nums=[5,0,5,0,5]
minmax(nums)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake lies in the way you access element in your for loop

```py
for i in List[1:-1]:
        if List[i] < List[i-1] and List[i] < List[i+1]:
            mins.append(List[i])
        elif List[i] > List[i-1] and i> List[i+1]:
            maxs.append(List[i])
```

indeed, `i` here is an element of `List` not the index of this element, therefore, `List[i]` doesn't have any sense neither `List[i+1]` nor `List[i-1]`.

One fix could be using [enumerate](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_enumerate.asp#:%7E:text=Python%20enumerate%20%28%29%20Function%201%20Definition%20and%20Usage.,Defining%20the%20start%20number%20of%20the%20enumerate%20object.) to track either the current value of the list but also its index :

```py
for n, i in enumerate(List[1:-1]):
        if List[n] < List[n-1] and List[n] < List[n+1]:
            mins.append(List[n])
        elif List[n] > List[n-1] and i> List[n+1]:
            maxs.append(List[n])
```

I strongly encourage you to use a debugger to understand this behavior.